# temporary table count filtered rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

My tables are invoices and sometimes invoice equal zero so I want to calculate my recurring clients. and of course invoice with zero amount is considered as a recurring client...
So I decide to summarize by clients total amounts.
This is my code DAX:

```
NewC = 
Var Clients = 
CALCULATETABLE(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'public invoices',
            'public invoices'[GroupeClient]
        ),
        "sales",sum('public invoices'[Amount])
    )
)

var filterclient =FILTER(Clients,[sales]>0)

return countrows(filterclient)
```

But my result is that it counts all clients and not only clients with a total amount superior to zero.

What is weird is that if I do a table in power, of a list of client with my measurements below, it shows me a list of clients with a sales up to zero.

So my second var filter client seems to work but why in my result It counts all my clients and not only clients filtered?

Comment: Why you are filtering clients after the calculation. Do it before, I think this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fac, my error is in my sum. It sum all fields of the table and not the sum for each client.
To solve this, I used calculate before sum and then it works:

Var Clients =
CALCULATETABLE(
ADDCOLUMNS(
SUMMARIZE(
'public invoices',
'public invoices'[GroupeClient]
),
"sales",calculate(sum('public invoices'[Amount]))
)
)

var filterclient =FILTER(Clients,[sales]>0)

return countrows(filterclient)